# Any Idea How to test Actions on Google for Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

I'm trying to test my finance app. We want to add an Actions.
But the problem is when we want to test them because we have to push the app on Google Play (just for testing).
We have linked account google and firebase ok.
When I tried to publish the app.

Google Play Console gives a message saying that the app has actions and can't test it.

I know that Actions on Google for Android are in Experimental.

I have this info

https://developers.google.com/actions/app/

Thank you.

Comment: Since you have an account then I guess this is what you need.. > https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180?hl=en If you didn't get your signed version yet you can check this documentation: > https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: Thank you , but It dosen't solves my problem :/ I need to test the actions.